# H2 database empty between tests

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, junit, integration-testing

i am currently fighting with the following problem. I have currently for each integration scenario a single unit test class. Further I have there methods like creating or retrieving data in/from database (embedded H2 db). The problem I have is that after creating (creation is first called - @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)) I would like to retrieve entity from the database in the next method call. However, my database is empty and I cannot really retrieve details stored in the previous call. Here is the definition of my class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import({ TestApplicationConfig.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.myapp.persistence")
@Transactional
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SimpleControllerTest extends AbstractTest { ... }
```

It is important to have the shared status across all test method calls. Database is being dropped and re-created each time I execute my tests. It is a Spring REST application, service layer is already annotated with @Transactional, JPA with Hibernate is used at the persistence layer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: TBH order dependent tests aren't good practice. Also have you tried `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`

Comment: It's about integration tests. It would be really bad to reproduce all the staff created in the previous calls...

Comment: If you need some shared data then maybe consider saving it before all tests with `@Before` or `@BeforeClass`?

Comment: but even then I need to create and persist data from the scratch. What I would like to have is an empty db on starting integration tests put some data by calling my REST services, retrieve those data and use it with other tests. It is about testing real use-cases...

Comment: You can then implement your tests as whole scenarios e.g. don't test single features like adding item in one test and deleting item in the second. Test whole flow where in single test you add item and later in the same test you delete it.

Comment: thanks - yes I also thought about this solution but not sure whether that's the best one choice caus I need to organize the test code so that a meintenance is simple later... Other approach would be to use own Tomcat instance for integration tests, build Jenkins pipeline, execute tests first against Test-Tomcat aaplication and then deploy it